# Syntac error 'isdigit' problem in python3

Tags: python-3.x

```
import random
x = random.randint(0,100)
i = 0
while True:
    n=input("sheitanet ricxvi an Q gamosvlistvis:  ")
    if n >=101 or n < 0:
        print("sheikvanet ricxvi 0 dan 100 is shualedshi!!!!")
        continue
    if n == "Q":
        print("Bye Bye!")
        break
    if n not n.isdigit():
        print("gtxovt sheitanot ricxvi an Q")
        continue
    elif n == x:
        print("Tqven gamoicanit chafiqrebuli ricxvi!", i, "Cdashi")
        break
    elif n < x:
        print("tqveni shetanili ricxvi naklebia chafiqrebul ricxvze")
        i+=1
    elif n > x:
        print("tqveni ricxvi metia chafiqrebul ricxzze")
        i+=1
```

Since I'm new to programming, I don't really know what it's trying to tell me. I'm using the if n.isdigit(): to check to see if what the user entered is a valid number.

```
if n not n.isdigit():
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

also i need to make 
if n is between +- 20 
print("ur close")
something like this!

Comment: It's just `if not n.isdigit()`...

Comment: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'
  File "C:\Users\SGamr\Desktop\Work\gam\game.py", line 13, in <module>
    if not n.isdigit():

Comment: `n` is not an `int` but a `str` object from your input. So the method `isdigit()` exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if not n.isdigit():
    print("gtxovt sheitanot ricxvi an Q")
    continue
```

Just like that, without `n`